# How to add two consequetive colors to bars in a plotly barchart with values of one pandas column

Tags: colors, plotly, bar-chart

I would like to have a barchart where two colors are used for the bars, f.i. first blue next red, than blue again followed by red.
In matplotlib this is possible see below code.
I would like to do this also with plotly express.
Suggestions are appreciated.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(freqfinal, columns=['teller' , 'frequenties']) # df = dataframe, pd staat voor Pandas
    
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_1.teller, y=df_1.frequenties, showlegend= True))
       
    fig.show()
    
    # in matplotlib, it works with two colors 

    bar_colors = ['red', 'blue']
    ax = df_1['frequenties'].plot(kind='bar', color=bar_colors, title= 'series per 100 trekkingen') # barchart met behulp van matplotlib
    ax.set_xlabel('volgorde frequenties') #label x-as
    ax.set_ylabel('serie grootte') # label y-as
    plt.show()
```

See above, first part is the plotly base code second part is the matplotlib code where I was succesful to have the two colors side by side

Answer (score 0):

If you give us a list of desired color combinations for the marker color, we can create the expected color scheme.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'teller': list('ABCDEFGHIK'), 'frequenties': np.random.randint(0,50,10)})

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_1.teller, y=df_1.frequenties, marker_color=['blue','red']*5, showlegend=True))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I would like only two colors. Thanks but I hoped that the =>marker_color=['blue','red'], would do the trick similar as in Matplotlib=> bar_colors = ['red', 'blue']. I added this to my code as follows: fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_1.teller, y=df_1.frequenties, marker_color=['blue','red'], showlegend= True)) with result that only the first two bars are blue en red and the rest of the bars are black. Any suggestions?

Comment: In plotly, I need a list of the same color as the number of x-axis. I am not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: Other question: how can I add to my comment a figure (result) in order to show what I mean.

Comment: The number of x-axis is the "teller".

Comment: It is possible to update the question. Totally disconnected questions are not recommended, but